# Offset equivalent to translate then rotate

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

The goal is to find what vx and vy must be so the two codes below are equivalent.

```
//this is the behaviour I want
ctx.translate(x,y);
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,10);

//find vx and vy so both this below is equivalent to above
var vx = ?;
var vy = ?;
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.fillRect(0 + vx, 0 + vy,10,10);
```

Comment: naming { vx, vy } two vars that describes a rotated offset seems just confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to rotate the point the other way around.

```
Tk.rotatePt.x = function(x,y,rad_angle,anchorX,anchorY){
    return Math.cos(rad_angle) * (x-anchorX) - Math.sin(rad_angle) * (y-anchorY) + anchorX;
}
Tk.rotatePt.y = function(x,y,rad_angle,anchorX,anchorY){
    return Math.sin(rad_angle) * (x-anchorX) + Math.cos(rad_angle) * (y-anchorY) + anchorY;
}

var vx = Tk.rotatePt.x(x,y,-angle,0,0);
var vy = Tk.rotatePt.y(x,y,-angle,0,0);
```